# Определить id тега, на который нажали в WebBrowser (c#)

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Создаю приложение, которое использует компонент WebBrower (Среда VS). Необходимо при нажатии на документ(страницу) в WebBrowser получить id тега, который был нажат. Пытался сделать некоторыми методом:

```
HtmlElement link = ModuleWebBrowser.Document.ActiveElement;
string url = link.GetAttribute("class");
```

Но строка получается пустой. Возможно ли узнать id тега div, на который нажали? И каким способом? Единственный способ, который отобразил мне теги - innerHtml

Comment: `link.GetAttribute("id");`?

Comment: Да, я так пробовал. Ничего не возвращается. Думаю сделать обработчик нажатия на тег в html форме и через js вызывать метод в самой программе.